# Why does Listings package not display anything in draft mode?

Tags: listings

I'm writing a C++ course for secondary students and wanted to display some source code in a nice way (indenting, eventually coloration) and tried the Listings package.
But I have a problem, the file compile with no problem and then, when I look at the place where my code is supposed to appear, it is empty. Neither code or spaces. Why?
I am not really a LaTex expert, I just wrote my thesis with it (no source code in it), so maybe it is something very simple I missed...
Working on a mac with texmaker in utf8.

The minimum (non-)working example is:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C++}

\begin{document}
    \section{Inline listings are shown}
        \lstinline!void main() {return 0}!

    \section{Environment listings are blank}
        \begin{lstlisting}
void main() { return 0; }
        \end{lstlisting}

    \section{Included file listings are blank}
    \lstinputlisting{ex_comments.cpp}
\end{document}
```

This hides listings in `lstlisting` environments and files included with `\lstinputlisting` as can bee seen in this output:

[image]

Comment: You should post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of the code that you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 30):

Seems like listings package doesn't play well with draft option in the document class. The [`listings` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) suggests passing the `final` option to the package in chapter 2.2 *Package loading*. This solution works for me:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
...
\usepackage[final]{listings}
...
```

That way I've got both black marks on overfull lines and listings. The same trick works with graphicx package.

Comment: Works very well :)

Comment: Still work now, 2020.

Answer (score 7):

`listings.sty` can not handle utf8-characters. If this is your problem use `listingsutf8` or alternetively package `minted`. If this is not an answer to your problem, then as usual: provide a small minimal example ...

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem... I always get problems when I want to use utf8... I will stick to latin1 now :)

Comment: Oops. I answered too early... In fact it does work with the snippet, but not with the code section or inclusion...

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
    
\begin{document}

\section{Snippet}
\lstset{language=C++}
\lstinline!void main() {return 0}!

\section{section}
\lstset{language=C++}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
void main()
{
return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\section{include}
\lstinputlisting{ex_comments.cpp}

\end{document}

Comment: @Lucas: do not use the option draft in the documentclass

Comment: Ohhh...
This time it works perfectly! That happens when you try to use commands you don't know, supposing which is the effect...
Anyway, thank you very much!

Lucas